# Using `fifelse` within data.table `by`, where test column is part of `by`

Tags: r, data.table

I want to add a column to a `data.table` that is a sequence within groups defined using `by`, but using a condition on one of the columns used in the `by` clause. I tried using `fifelse` as in the following example:

```R
dt <- data.table::data.table(
  id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3),
  clk = c(1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 5),
  val = LETTERS[1:6]
)

dt[, seq_clk := fifelse(clk != 0, seq_len(.N), NA_integer_), by = .(id, clk)]
```

This results in the following error

> Error in fifelse(clk != 0, seq_len(.N), NA_integer_) :
> Length of 'yes' is 2 but must be 1 or length of 'test' (1).

The result I'm expecting to get can be achieved by the following code

```R
dt[, seq_2 := seq_len(.N), by = .(id, clk)][
, seq_clk := fifelse(clk != 0, seq_2, NA_integer_)][
  , seq_2 := NULL]
```

which gives

```R
   id clk val seq_clk
1:  1   1   A       1
2:  1   1   B       2
3:  2   0   C      NA
4:  2   2   D       1
5:  2   2   E       2
6:  3   5   F       1
```

Although the above code works, I don't understand why the one-liner in the first example does not work. It seems that the issue is with applying `fifelse` to a column listed in the `by` clause. It works fine with columns not in the `by`.

I've also noticed that other functions do not work as I expect in this situation. For example:

```R
dt[, sum_id_by_clk := fifelse(clk != 0, sum(id), NA_integer_), by = .(id, clk)]
```

does not give an error, but produces incorrect results:

```R
   id clk val sum_id_by_clk
1:  1   1   A             1
2:  1   1   B             1
3:  2   0   C            NA
4:  2   2   D             2
5:  2   2   E             2
6:  3   5   F             3
```

I'd expect the values in the last column to be 2 for rows 1-2 and 4 for rows 4-5.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to number the columns within each `id, clk` group while skipping rows where `clk == 0`

For this, data.table's `rowid()` function can be used conveniently:

```
dt[clk != 0, seq_clk := rowid(id, clk)][]
```

> ```
>       id   clk    val seq_clk
> 1:     1     1      A       1
> 2:     1     1      B       2
> 3:     2     0      C      NA
> 4:     2     2      D       1
> 5:     2     2      E       2
> 6:     3     5      F       1
> ```

Row 3 was excluded from the *update by reference* and gets `NA` by default.

---

The OP was wondering why calculations on grouping variables do not give the expected result. Here is an attempt of an explanation.

According to `?data.table`, the general form of data.table syntax is:

```
DT[ i,  j,  by ] # + extra arguments
    |   |   |
    |   |    -------> grouped by what?
    |    -------> what to do?
     ---> on which rows?
```

The way to read this out loud is: "Take `DT`, subset rows by `i`, *then* compute `j` grouped by `by`.

So, normally variables appearing in `by` *are not meant* to be used in a `j` expression. This is further underlined by the explanation of the *special symbol* `.SD` (see `?.SD`):

> `.SD` is a `data.table` containing the **S**ubset of `x`'s **D**ata for each group,
> excluding any columns used in `by` (or `keyby`).

This can be verified by

```
dt[clk != 0, print(.SD), by = .(id, clk)][]
```

> ```
>       val seq_clk
> 1:      A       1
> 2:      B       2
>       val seq_clk
> 1:      D       1
> 2:      E       2
>       val seq_clk
> 1:      F       1
> Empty data.table (0 rows and 2 cols): id,clk
> ```

The grouping variables can be accessed via the special symbol `.BY`, e.g.,

```
dt[clk != 0, str(.BY), by = .(id, clk)][]
```

> ```
> List of 2
>  $ id : num 1
>  $ clk: num 1
> List of 2
>  $ id : num 2
>  $ clk: num 2
> List of 2
>  $ id : num 3
>  $ clk: num 5
> Empty data.table (0 rows and 2 cols): id,clk
> ```

So, each grouping variable exists once only for each group which explains why `sum(id)` returns only `id`.

Comment: Thanks, it had help me to solve the issue and to better understand data.table. One comment - I'm not sure I agree with the claim "normally variables appearing in by are not meant to be used in a j expression" - maybe this isn't the most common use case, but I can think of use cases where one would need to use the grouping variables (and they are available in the j expression).  Last thing - @akrun's answer bellow also solves my problem, in the original spirit of my question. I think it completes this answer and adds additional insight, so for those interested I'd recommend reading it as well.

Answer (score 3):

We may change the name of the grouping column

```
dt[, seq_clk := fifelse(clk != 0, seq_len(.N), NA_integer_),
     by = .(id, clk2 = clk)]
```

-output

```
> dt
      id   clk    val seq_clk
   <num> <num> <char>   <int>
1:     1     1      A       1
2:     1     1      B       2
3:     2     0      C      NA
4:     2     2      D       1
5:     2     2      E       2
6:     3     5      F       1
```

---

Or `rep` the `test` part

```
dt[, seq_clk := fifelse(rep(clk, .N) != 0, seq_len(.N), 
       NA_integer_), by = .(id, clk)]
> 
> dt
      id   clk    val seq_clk
   <num> <num> <char>   <int>
1:     1     1      A       1
2:     1     1      B       2
3:     2     0      C      NA
4:     2     2      D       1
5:     2     2      E       2
6:     3     5      F       1
```

It is possible that the grouping column when it is used in the condition, it uses only the first element

```
> dt[, length(clk) , clk]
     clk    V1
   <num> <int>
1:     1     1
2:     0     1
3:     2     1
4:     5     1
```

whereas by changing the grouping column

```
> dt[, length(clk) , .(clk2 = clk)]
    clk2    V1
   <num> <int>
1:     1     2
2:     0     1
3:     2     2
4:     5     1
```

and `fifelse/ifelse` all requires all arguments to be of same length (although the `NA_integer_` is of length 1 - which recycles, it is better to replicate that as well)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. So the issue is that columns that are in the 'by' are length-1 in the group, so in the specific case of 'fifelse', the length of the test wasn't matching the length of the YES vector? I was also wondering about two things - (a) when we rename the column in the 'by', shouldn't we have a column with the new name? and (b) are there any performance differences between the two methods? (renaming the column / rep() the test).